# Is it possible to develop Flex w/ ASP.NET projects on OSX via remote connection?

Tags: asp.net, apache-flex, macos

I recently completed a Flex app (using Flex Builder 3, PHP, and MySQL) on my Mac and now I want to write a very similar application to use on a client's ASP.NET site.

Flex Builder apparently refuses to set up an ASP.NET project if there's no local IIS server (which I don't have).

Is there a way I could develop the Flex app locally using a remote testing server?

note- Running IIS on Parallels is not an option for this particular project...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What method are you using to communicate between the Flex project and the ASP.NET project? If you're communicating using web services, you shouldn't need to set up a server technology in Flex Builder - you only need a crossdomain.xml file on the client server.